# Get branch name in case of pull request jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I am using Jenkins multibranch pipeline pull request feature when i print env.BRANCH_NAME it prints PR-pullrequestnumber. instead of that i want to get branch name how could i get it ?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the branch name from `env.CHANGE_BRANCH` in case of a pull request.

Comment: If you want to see all environment variables. Try sh "env" in pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You will get the exact branch name after merging the code. It's just to differ

Comment: But if i want to use that branch name somewhere then? shouldn't it be provided in some other parameter ?

Comment: when you view environment variable with command `env` there's variable $CHANGE_TARGET. That contain's you branch name. I use that whenever doing deployment without merging the repo.